# How to set XAML Design View to be on right by default?

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface, settings, xaml-designer

When we set split orientation to Vertical for XAML Designer in Visual Studio,
Design View is positioned on left.

Is it possible to make it on right by default?

[image: XAML Designer - Design view on right]